# "Allow from" in a range in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I'd like to add a range of IPs to Apache httpd 2.2 where the third octet is in a range:

```
X.Y.192-254
```

I can do this:

```
Allow from X.Y.192
Allow from X.Y.193
. . .
Allow from Y.Y.254
```

But, that's pretty verbose. I'm basically trying to add a list of partial IPs.

Is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Allow` can use a network address and mask, per https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow with either a mask or a number of bits.

192 to 254 (255 in fact) corresponds to the first two bits of the last (4th) byte to be set to 1.

So `192.0.2.192/26` will match `192.0.2.192` to `192.0.2.255`.

If you really need not to match the `.255` then you will need multiple `Allow` statements. Or add `deny from 192.0.2.255`. Result will then depend on the `order` setting.